# Using Pop Up dialog window input inside the parent class controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have requirement , I am opening a dialog window and asking for user input. Based on that user input I have to perform a task in parent class controller.

But I am facing a problem that when the dialog window opens angular passes the control to the next statements and in that case it executes the code which requires dialog window input even before a user enters the input in the dialog window.

Is there any way out for this . I have got a solution for this to move the code that needs to be executed on user input inside the dialog controller. But there is a lot of code and would take lot of time to sort the issues out.

Is there any alternative barring the above solution?

Comment: please add your code snippet or create jsfiddle

Comment: Is this question about AngularJS or Angular?